# installing habitrpg.el in ergoemacs

Tags: emacs, emacs24, ergoemacs

I am using ergoemacs for windows downloaded from http://ergoemacs.org/index.html. The version is as follows:

GNU Emacs 24.2.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601) of 2012-08-29 on MARVIN
ErgoEmacs distribution 2.0.0

When I install habitrpg.el (https://github.com/ryjm/habitrpg.el) as per the instruction I get the following error:

Symbol's function definition is void: cl-eval-when.

I tried commenting this instruction and I get again the same error for cl-defstruct. I believe this is got to do with the cl.el but I am not sure which alternative cl file I can use or if there is any other habitrpg.el i can use which is compatible with ErgoEmacs. Please do the needful and let me know if you need any more information regarding the same.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, there are 2 problems:

- habitrpg does `(require 'cl)` whereas it should do `(require 'cl-lib)`.  You should report that to the author.
- your Emacs doesn't come with `cl-lib` built-in, so you need to install it (which you can do from `M-x package-list RET`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I installed cl-lib 0.5 from install packages  and changed (require 'cl) to (require 'cl-lib). Yet, I am getting the same error. Any other idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: If the files you modified have byte-compiled (`*.elc`) versions, your change typically won't be seen unless you recompile them, as Emacs will load the compiled file by preference.